# Multi-part values as hash key/set entries in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, dictionary, duplicates

In Python I can use tuples (or any hashable object) as dictionary keys or set members. It's useful for deduping:

```py
cool_podcast_guests = set([
    ('Emma', 'Suter'),
    ('Dave', 'Warner'),
    ('Evie', 'Wilde'),
    ('Emma', 'Suter'),
]) 

for forename, surname in cool_podcast_guests:
    interview_these[(forename, surname)] = lookup_address(forename, surname)
```

This (simple-mindedly assuming that forename-surname pairs refer to unique people) deduplicates the list of candidates.

How might you do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

### Some Basic Options

If you just want "automatic" deduplication, you have a few basic choices:

1. Use a Symbol instead of an Array or String, as a Symbol is unique by definition.
2. Use an Array of String objects as the key.
3. Use a combined String composed of parts of names to create the key.
4. Use a Set rather than a Hash, since a Set guarantees uniqueness for objects other than Hash keys.

Note that when assigning to matching Hash keys, the last value entered overwrites whatever value may already be there. This is true regardless of the key's type; a Hash can only contain unique keys.

Also, note that Ruby doesn't really have tuples, and even "immutable" objects (other than a Symbol) are rarely truly immutable even when frozen. Even constants can be overwritten in Ruby, albeit with a warning; this is widely considered a feature, not a bug, by the language maintainers.

### An Example Using Your Inputs and Elided Code

Assuming you aren't worried about clobbering "duplicates" where two different people with different information happen to share the same first and last names or a common email address, you can simply assign your values like this:

```rb
def scrape_address forename, surname
  # do whatever you want to do here
end

guests = [
    ['Emma', 'Suter'],
    ['Dave', 'Warner'],
    ['Evie', 'Wilde'],
    ['Emma', 'Suter'],
]

# Needs to be accessible outside the scope
# of the block below; there are other ways
# to do this, so consider this approach as
# only an illustration. Instance variables
# or closures would be good alternatives.
interview_contact_email = {}

# Use your existing lookup, relying on
# the uniqueness of `forename + surname`
# to actually be a unique key.
guests.map do |forename, surname|
  name  = [forename, surname].join " "
  email = scrape_address forename, surname
  interview_contact_email[name] = email
end
```

### A Better Alternative

Since names, emails, and other data aren't inherently unique, you may consider alternatives such as assigning a UUIDv4 or unique database key as an ID for each person, and treat deduplication as a separate exercise. That's because you simply can't guarantee that there isn't more than one "Jane Doe" in a dataset, or that "Jane Doe" and "John Doe" both use `jdoe@example.com` as a shared email address.

The scope of data cleansing and validation is largely outside the scope of your original question, but I mention it here because someone will invariably object that assuming names form a unique key or that multiple keys can't have the same value will lead you to the Dark Side, where they have delicious cookies.

There are plenty of other ways to do what you want to do, but as long as you remember that Hash keys are unique but their values can be overwritten you can do what you want easily enough.

### See Also

- [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Hash.html), including lots of information about the semantics of basic and custom key objects.
- [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Symbol.html), which is often used when you want to assert identify rather than value. You will most often see symbols as Hash keys or method names, but they are fundamental to how Ruby works internally.
- [String](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/String.html), which are the Ruby object types currently contained within your tuples. They have lots of methods for joining, concatenation, interpolation, and various transformations that would allow you to create meaningful Hash keys.
- [Random::Formatter#uuid](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/stdlibs/random/Random/Formatter.html#method-i-uuid) can be used to generate UUIDv4 identifiers as keys in the event that you *aren't* sure that both people named `Emma Suter` in your example code are actually the same person.

Comment: How about `interview_contact_email = guests.to_h do |name|
  [name, scrape_address(*name)]
end` ([demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZA9DoJAEIVjuzewm8IEf9BoZ0MnJ7CwIISsu4OSwEL2B2PCTWwo9FKexsXFBE3sJt_MvHnzbndpjte2fRidLrfP0XjCtIQA1oRwTEExSStMKOcSlYK0lChogT4oI7uCALwXFgFsCApOyMmg0soqRLYHEHlhUVDPB29vNEov9nu8ozV2-EClGPKwzhzPco4D_KsSE5IJW9vxS8JKoSnTCRY0y-1tZ2Kly-QMvISms9pYpag3__XVdN7RWez8V_BH1iXUB_UJ7AU))? Does it have issues compared to yours?

Comment: @KellyBundy `name` in this case would be an `Array` so to duplicate exactly what is produced here it would be `[name.join(' '),scrape_address(*name)]`, but to answer your question *no* there is no discernible difference, they both suffer from the same issues. While what you have posted is much more idiomatic ruby I prefer the traditional `guests.each_with_object({})` implementation because there are less allocations to disposable objects and in the case of the duplicate ` ['Emma', 'Suter']` it allows you to better handle this collision using methods like `Hash#merge`

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using Ruby hashes, which can have arrays as keys:

```rb
n0 = [ :Dave, :Willis ]
n1 = [ :Sam, :Jones ]
guests = {n0 => 'addr1', n1 => 'addr2'}
guests.include?(n0) # => true
guests[n0] # => 'addr1'
n0.hash # => 110002110
```

Note that Python and Ruby semantics differ. Modifying a component of the key in Ruby damages the hash index-- so don't change the Ruby key without rehashing:

```rb
n0[0] = :Emma
guests[n0] # => nil
```

but:

```rb
guests.rehash # => {[:Emma, :Willis]=>'addr1', [:Sam, :Jones]=>'addr2'}
guests.include?(n0) # => true
guests[n0] # => 'addr1'
```

In Python, a tuple can be a key (unless they contain mutable values) but a list can't:

```py
>>> guests = {}
>>> tuple_dave = ('Dave', 'Warner')
>>> list_dave =   ['Dave', 'Warner']
>>> guests[tuple_dave] = "addr1"
>>> guests[list_dave] = "addr1"
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> h = ('foo', ['bar', 'zot'])
>>> guests[h] = "addr3"
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> guests
{('Dave', 'Warner'): 'addr1'}
```

Changing `tuple_dave`'s value doesn't affect `guests` at all in Python. Reassigning `tuple_dave` creates a new tuple that has nothing to do with the old value.

```py
>>> tuple_dave = ('Dave', 'Smith')
>>> guests
{('Dave', 'Warner'): 'addr1'}
>>> guests[tuple_dave] = "addr2"
>>> guests
{('Dave', 'Warner'): 'addr1', ('Dave', 'Smith'): 'addr2'}
```

In Python if you want change an existing dictionary entry's key, you can't. You'll need to delete the key then re-add it.